# How To Piped Terminal Command Output To Zenity Progress Dialog Text?

Tags: linux, bash, zenity

I have a simple app with some bash command, for example `apt update`, and I want to pipe its output to `--text` parameter in zenity Progress dialog , i tried some options after googling like :

```
gksudo apt update | xargs -L1 -I % zenity --progress --text=% --percentage=0 --auto-close --auto-kill
```

but all i got is blinking window!

So, how can i make the output appearing in zenity window with progress percentage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot *make the output appearing in zenity window with progress percentage*, because for a percentage computation the information what amounts to 100 % is needed, and here it is not known beforehand how much output the `apt update` command will generate.

What you can do is have an animated progress bar while `apt update` is outputting something. Since standard output to a pipe is normally fully buffered, the buffering has to be changed with `stdbuf`:

```
gksudo stdbuf -oL apt update | zenity --progress --pulsate --auto-close --auto-kill
```

Comment: In theory you could compute the current progress from `apt update`'s output by checking how many of the URLs from `apt-cache policy` got checked so far. However, showing the output of `apt update` (missing here) might only be possible *after* the command finished, so there is no point in a progress bar.